# iOS update via iTunes to latest MINOR version?

Tags: ios, itunes, software-update

I have iOS 14.7.1 and can't update to 14.8.1 directly in iPhone.

iTunes wants to update only to iOS 15.1:

[image: itunes]

How to update to 14.8.1 via iTunes?

[image]

Comment: The signing window for 14.x iOS versions has already been closed by Apple. On iOS devices you can't install an OS that has not been signed for your specific device. If your device supports iOS 15 then you can only update to that version. Apple only allows updates to the most recent version for your device (if an update has just been released for usually about a week update to the version before is still possible).

Comment: You can review this page: https://ipsw.me Select your device and it will tell you which versions you can use, including IPSW files you could use to restore the phone with iTunes if it's supported.

Comment: So why do I see 14.8.1 in Software Update? Seems strange that Apple would leave me without the option to update especially if it is critical.

Comment: @Ezekiel I don't see 14.8.1 at all on that page, strange.

Comment: 14.8.1 was only released two days ago. See https://support.apple.com/HT201435 to see if you can get it directly to your phone To run the update via iTunes, you'll have to wait until ipsw.com have it listed, then do it manually - opt/click the Update button & choose the file. I was just successful at getting the update OTA on a 6S, iTunes would only offer 15.1 [which isn't all that bad btw, I'm using it on an SE2]

Comment: [note for me] Bookmark https://ipsw.me/iPhone8,1 to see if they eventually list it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was at least able to download it, but installation failed so I will wait for ipsw and will try manual installation via file.

Comment: @Tetsujin looks like they will not release it. But I was able to update via phone somehow after many retries..so can you post your comment as an answer? The downloading from ipsw and then manually updating in iTunes is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you have difficulties updating OTA, then you can manually fetch the updater, an .ipsw file, & run it manually from iTunes [Finder in newer macOS.]

If you are trying to update to the latest iOS, then iTunes will usually find the correct file for you. If, as in this case, there is a security update for an earlier iOS then you may have to fetch it manually.

[ipsw.me](https://ipsw.me/) contains lists of .ipsw files for all devices, going back into the mists of time. They do not store the content, merely the correct addresses to where Apple keeps these updates.
They are only useful for as long as Apple are still signing the update - usually a couple of weeks after the next update is released; the window of opportunity can be short.

If you download one of these, then in iTunes you  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  click the Update button & you will be asked to choose a file to update from, rather than the automatic process. Once chosen, assuming it's the correct file & still being signed, then the update will proceed in the same way as any regular update.